# Manager Identity error when running a pipeline in Data Factory with Staging Blob Storage + Polybase to a Azure DataWarehouse

Tags: azure-data-factory, staging, azure-synapse, polybase

I am getting this error message when trying to use Polybase + Enabling Staging Blob Storage to pull data from Azure SQL to Azure DW Database.

Managed Service Identity has not been enabled on this server. Please enable Managed Service Identity and try again.

I've tried to create a Managed Identity user assigning it to a web service and giving it permission linking this user to a AAD Group that has owner permission in the database, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, logon in Azure PowerShell with your username/password .
Secondly, run the following command to assign your DB DataWarehouse Server.

Set-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroup  -ServerName   -AssignIdentity

Answer (score 0):

Is your sink , source and blob are part of the same subscription ? Since the error is complaining about the SQDWH access , I think you need to check this out .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse#managed-identity.

Do let me know how it goes .

I am assuming that you are using the authentication type = managed identity on the sink side .

We need to the give the adequate permission to the ADF . Navigate to the below  on Azure portal .
Dashboard->SQL data warehouses-><> - Query editor (preview)

```
CREATE USER [your ADF Name ] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
EXEC sp_addrolemember db_owner, [your ADF Name];
```

Now execute the pipeline , it should work fine .

I wanted to repro your issue and so I deliberately removed the permission for the ADF

```
EXEC sp_droprolemember db_owner, [your ADF Name];
```

I see the below error ( this is not whay you reported )

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=FailedDbOperation,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error happened when loading data into SQL Data Warehouse.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=User does not have permission to perform this action.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=15247,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=15247,State=1,Message=User does not have permission to perform this action.,},],'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy data1",
    "details": []
}
```

I think that there is something else going on with your pipeline .

Comment: Hi Mate, thank you for your help. Yes, source and blob are part of the same subscription. I have done already these steps but it is still stuck in this error message.

Comment: What is confusing is, do I need to create a user just? or Do I need to create a login as well? I am also reading about Storage firewall config as it could be the issue why the sql dw is not reaching the blob storage to pull the data.

Comment: You need to have an user . I am able to do what you are doing without any issue . I think there is more to this issue . If you have a support plan please reach out to them and some body will work with you to resolution . 

in case you dont't have a support please 
send an email to azcommunity@microsoft.com with the below details, so that we can create a one-time-free support ticket for you to work closely on this matter.  

Thread URL: 


Subscription ID:  


Please let me know once you have done the same

Comment: I have updated my answer , i hope it helps you get closer to your resolution .

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user and login with db_owner permissions. Login with the user to test if it actually works.
PS DF Polybase is not that great as you might think... Under the hood it shards the files to smaller ones, dumps the data to tempdb tables, only then loads it to your table, which takes quite a while if you have billions of records.
I did a lot of tests with it and we ended up using CTAS directly, as it turned out to be 10x faster.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas